# in angular js, how to store variable for use in other http functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth

I have the following controller:

```
angular.
  module('phoneList').
  component('phoneList', {
    templateUrl: '/phone-list.template.html',
    controller: ['$http',
      function PhoneListController($http) {
        var self = this;

        var access_token = '';



          var data = $.param({
              grant_type: 'password',
              username: 'test',
              password: 'test',
              client_id:'1234',
              client_secret:'12345',
          });

          var config = {
              headers : {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
              }
          }

          $http.post('/o/token/', data, config)
          .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              self.access_token = data['access_token'];
              console.log(access_token);
          })
          .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
              $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
                  "<hr />status: " + status +
                  "<hr />headers: " + header +
                  "<hr />config: " + config;
          });


          var header = {
                  headers : {
                      'Authorization': 'Bearer '+self.access_token
                  }
              }

        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'api/posts/', headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+self.access_token}}).then(function(response) {
          self.phones = response.data;

        });
      }
    ]
  });
```

I want to use the access token returned from this function that lasts several days.  I don't want to get a new token every time but determine if the token is expired or if another needs to be retrieved:

```
$http.post('/o/token/', data, config)
          .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              self.access_token = data['access_token'];
              console.log(access_token);
          })
```

In my get function:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'api/posts/', headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+self.access_token}}).then(function(response) {
          self.phones = response.data;

        });
```

**How do I accomplish this?**

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your app's name is `myapp`.
Then, create a module called `authentication` where you can put a factory that will retrieve the token and put it in a session storage. In the same factory, you can add a `getToken` service that will return your session storage data :

```
angular.module('authentication').factory('authenticationService', function($http, $se){
    function authenticate(){
        $http.post('/o/token/', data, config)
              .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  $sessionStorage.access_token = data['access_token'];
              });
    }    
    function getToken(){
        return $sessionStorage.access_token;
    }
    return {
        authenticate:authenticate,
        getToken:getToken
    };
});
```

In your main module, call the the run function and invoke your service :

```
angular.module('myapp').run(function(authenticationService){
    authenticationService.authenticate().then(function(){
    // Redirection to the next route
    });    
});
```

In your controller, just inject the `authenticationService` factory and retrieve the token with the `authenticationService.getToken()` instead of doing Ajax calls :

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'api/posts/', headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ authenticationService.getToken()}}).then(function(response) {
    self.phones = response.data;
});
```